# Some applications cover my top bar in dwm

Tags: window-manager, dwm, chrome

Recently, Google Chrome has been taking 100% screen space and has been covering my top bar. Its never done this before. I tried reinstalling and nothing changed.

I can post a screencap if anyone needs, but I assume its pretty straightforward what it looks like. I can still <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Drag</kbd> to move the window and see the top bar. But chrome keep maximizing.

Any ideas?

Comment: I use DWM and -DON'T- have this behavior, sorry. Will try some things when I get home and can test it out though. Might be good to list what patches you've done to config.h though

Comment: @Rob, only a couple applications do it. I've only got the "status on all monitors" patch, but have had it way before this behaviour started. Thanks.

Comment: its alt+shift+space to 'drop' a window from a floating state to tiled